# Android: How do you hide Tabs in the ActionBar?

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

I need to temporarily hide the `Tab` objects I've defined for my `ActionBar`. There is no `setVisibility` method on `Tab` objects, so I'm at a loss as to how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I'd try `setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD)`, to move back to the non-tab rendition. It's possible that, when you later call `setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS)` that you will need to re-establish your tabs, though.

**UPDATE**: Note that action bar tabs are deprecated in the "L" Developer Preview and should remain deprecated in future production Android releases. Consider using something else for tabs: `ViewPager` with a tabbed indicator, `FragmentTabHost`, etc.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks! The tabs come back just how I left them when they re-appear, so there is no need to add them back to the actionbar.

Comment: I just noticed an unwanted side effect. When the tabs re-appear the one the was previously selected fires an onTabSelected callback. I'd like to just hide/show the tabs without firing any events.

Comment: @Scienceprodigy: I suspect that won't be possible. Even if you remove and recreate the tabs, one will be selected, and its event will fire. Just teach your `TabListener` to ignore the first event after restoring the tabs.

Comment: The TabListener now ignores the event when I'm in the middle of changing nav modes. It's not as elegant as I would have liked, but it works.

Comment: I'm getting error - `The method setNavigationMode(int) is undefined for the type MainActivity`

Comment: @AntiMatter: `setNavigationMode()` is a method on `ActionBar`.

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare, is it possible to animate the hide and show ?

Comment: @noooooooob: Not that I am aware of. Also, see the update I just put on the answer.