# How to hide actionbar and show tabs

Tags: java, android

Many suggested that I should use:

```
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

and it shows me an actionbar with no title but with the application logo.
It was also suggested that I hide the logo and, when I did, the actionbar appeared empty and didn't hide.

Answer (score 0):

duplicate question , see :
[Android: Hide ActionBar, keep Tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14989372/android-hide-actionbar-keep-tabs) , 
 [Only display tabs in action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564947/only-display-tabs-in-action-bar)
[Android: How do you hide Tabs in the ActionBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522576/android-how-do-you-hide-tabs-in-the-actionbar)

You can hide the action bar at runtime by calling hide(). For example:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

[Full documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)

Comment: eclipse shows that getSupportActionBar() is undefined in Activity Class. only getActionBAr works